# IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12 GradientBoostingClassifier

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to plot the error on a GradientBoosting Classification, and I can't seem to find my mistake. I've looked up on the website for similar topics and didn't find any satisfying answer. 
Here is my code, hoping you guys might be able to help :

```
import time
tableau_duree_grd = np.zeros(145)
tableau_erreur_grd = np.zeros(145)

for b in range(5,150):
 start_time=time.time()
 grd=GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=b,validation_fraction= 0.1,n_iter_no_change=10,learning_rate=0.1,max_features=None)
 grd.fit(XTrainD,YTrainD)
 pred = grd.predict(XTestD)
 test_erreur_grd = np.mean(YTestD!=pred)
 end_time=time.time()
 duree=end_time-start_time
 tableau_duree_grd[b-5]=duree
 tableau_erreur_grd[b-5]=test_erreur_grd
```

The full error traceback :

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-9978ac0dd8ba> in <module>
  6     start_time=time.time()
  7     grd=GradientBoostingClassifier(n_estimators=b,validation_fraction= 0.1, n_iter_no_change=10,learning_rate=0.1,max_features=None)
----> 8     grd.fit(XTrainD,YTrainD)
  9     pred = grd.predict(XTestD)
 10     test_erreur_grd = np.mean(YTestD!=pred)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, monitor)
  1463         n_stages = self._fit_stages(X, y, y_pred, sample_weight, self._rng,
  1464                                     X_val, y_val, sample_weight_val,
-> 1465                                     begin_at_stage, monitor, X_idx_sorted)
  1466 
  1467         # change shape of arrays after fit (early-stopping or additional ests)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py in _fit_stages(self, X, y, y_pred, sample_weight, random_state, X_val, y_val, sample_weight_val, begin_at_stage, monitor, X_idx_sorted)
  1527             y_pred = self._fit_stage(i, X, y, y_pred, sample_weight,
  1528                                      sample_mask, random_state, X_idx_sorted,
-> 1529                                      X_csc, X_csr)
  1530 
  1531             # track deviance (= loss)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py in _fit_stage(self, i, X, y, y_pred, sample_weight, sample_mask, random_state, X_idx_sorted, X_csc, X_csr)
  1169 
  1170             residual = loss.negative_gradient(y, y_pred, k=k,
-> 1171                                               sample_weight=sample_weight)
  1172 
  1173             # induce regression tree on residuals

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\gradient_boosting.py in negative_gradient(self, y, pred, k, **kwargs)
   914             The index of the class
   915         """
--> 916         return y - np.nan_to_num(np.exp(pred[:, k] -
   917                                         logsumexp(pred, axis=1)))
   918 

  IndexError: index 12 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 12
```

Comment: Are we supposed to guess where this error happens and what a "GradientBoostingClassifier" is ? Please post a proper MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) AND the full error traceback.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit it

Comment: Can you show some data which can reproduce this. Also tell which version of numpy and scikit-learn are you using.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know the software, but it sounds like an off-by-one error. Programming languages typically count indices from 0 upwards, rather than from 1 upwards.

More specifically, on line 916 of gradient_boosting.py, the "k" variable probably contains the value 12, but value 11 should have been used instead.

It's also possible to get more info by adding print statements around line 916 of gradient_boosting.py, to get a better idea of what's going on in the logic when the error occurs.

Comment: The thing is I used this exact code for another GradientBoostingClassifier and didn't get an error that's why I was circumspect. But I'll try to narrow down the erreur maybe with some prints around line 916